# Cell Reusing issue swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have table view with cells. In my cell i have view with initial constraint of width equal to 0. In CellForRow.. method i update constraints like following:

```
  filledAreaWidth = viewModel.percentageFilled * cellWIdthCalculated

            self.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.filledAreaView.snp.updateConstraints({ (make) in
                make.width.equalTo(self.filledAreaWidth)
            })

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.65, animations: {
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
```

So, it animate width changing and it look like coloured bar drawing from left to right.

Problem is, when i scroll table, it animate it every time. I don't want to animate it for cell that is already created, only for new one.

Comment: @the4kman yes so what? i get animation effect again when i scroll to them.

Comment: @the4kman That's not really true. Cells are reused rather than *newly created* but in `cellForRow` all actions are called again.

Comment: @vadian yes, that what im talking about.. somehow i need to call update constraints without animation if cell was already shown on screen.

Comment: Add a boolean flag to your model which will change after the cell is displayed the first time.

Comment: add code for cellforrow

Comment: @vadian i guess modifying model though cell is not good by view of architecture but your advice seems good.

Comment: @AadilAli code i paste is called in cellforrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `[Int:Bool]` dictionary in your viewController to handle which cells are animated already and in tableView willDisplay method you can check and react according, something like this

```
var animatedCells: [Int:Bool] = [:]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if(animatedCells[indexPath.row] == nil)
          {
            animatedCells[indexPath.row] = true
            cell.makeYourAnimation()
          }
    }
```

You also need pass your animation code to your cell implementation

Hope this helps

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban i see that your animation code is in your cellForRow i recommend you pass this code to your cell implementation, in order to do this, let me know if you need further assistance

Comment: @Reiner Melian, ok, first i'l try your solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
//Edit Add this before

  let shownIndexes:[IndexPath] = []


 if (![self.shownIndexes containsObject:indexPath]) {
 [self.shownIndexes addObject:indexPath];
            // Animation code
  }
```

Use above method inside below delegate method and it will work. Load animation only once when tableview is loaded.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, 
forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if area is already filled or not:

```
filledAreaWidth = viewModel.percentageFilled * cellWIdthCalculated
if filledAreaWidth != self.filledAreaView.frame.size.width {

        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.filledAreaView.snp.updateConstraints({ (make) in
            make.width.equalTo(self.filledAreaWidth)
        })

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.65, animations: {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain the count of cells that have been displayed, in cell for row check whether the indexPath.row is less than the displayedCount. Let displayedCount always be maximum of displayed cells starting from -1. Like this

```
var rowsDisplayed = -1
```

in cellForRow

```
   if indexPath.row > rowsDisplayed {
          animate()
          rowsDisplayed = indexPath.row
}
```

Comment: i dont use that method, and dont even use storyboard for create cells.

Comment: Does awakeFromNib gets called in case of cell reuse? It doesnt, so the solution wont work.